# Identify first unique value in row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a row of numbers which I have converted to "TRUE" or "FALSE" and want to add a formula to the next row to identify the first instance of "TRUE", possibly with a '1', and the rest of the instances of "TRUE" with another identifier, '2', '3', etc...
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your row 1 has "TRUE" or "FALSE" in it, you can put this in `A2` and drag right:

```
=IF(A1=TRUE,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,TRUE),"")
```

[image]

Comment: does it make a difference if it is TRUE or "TRUE"  ie string versus boolean?

Comment: @ForwardEd - good point, this won't count the string version.

Comment: Funny thing is I am having a difficult time counting the string version of true

Comment: @ForwardEd - Same here! ...odd, even using `="TRUE"` as a cell's value, and countif with `"TRUE"` as a condition doesn't work.

Comment: @ForwardEd and Bruce:  I think that's been a problem for over ten years with `COUNTIF`.  But you can always use:  `=SUMPRODUCT(--(myRange="true"))`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sad to say but I am more than 10 years old...and by almost 4 decades now.  I had not heard of the issue with COUNTIFs  tahnks for the heads up and history lesson 8)